# Do OpenID Connect receivers support OpenID 1.0/2.0 delegation?

Tags: delegates, openid, backwards-compatibility, openid-connect

My OpenID identity URL includes a delegate link to my current OpenID provider. Should this identity URL still work when logging in to an OpenID Connect receiver (rather than an OpenID receiver)?

Comment: no, see also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27945031/openid-connect-delegation-with-google-now-that-they-are-deprecating-their-openid

Comment: also bigger picture https://www.sitepoint.com/community/t/the-death-of-openid-2-0/110947

Comment: related: web sign-in/indieauth as mentioned in http://stackoverflow.com/a/30094740/236081